# Should we create one or more tags for "power saving mode"?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have quite a few questions about the various "power saving mode" features in different phones. Some of them are about the feature in base Android available since Marshmallow or so. Others are about the "ultra power saving mode" that seems to be a Samsung-specific features. The existing questions seem to be mostly tagged with [power](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power), [battery-life](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-life), or (erroneously) with [power-options](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-options).

Should we add a new [power-saving-mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-saving-mode) tag? This would be specifically for questions about (problems with) that mode, whether they relate to battery life or not. And if so, should we add [ultra-power-saving-mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultra-power-saving-mode) for the problems specific to this feature (which is slightly different)?

Comment: Do you really feel an "ultra" tag needed? I've never even heard of that. // Edit: Googling it, it seems a Samsung specific thing?

Comment: The "ultra" can be made a synonym for the other one.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget [doze-mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doze-mode) in your list :)

We definitely should fix those wrongly tagged `power-options` – but for the remaining names also consider synonyms (unless there're good reasons for "keeping things apart"):

- [battery-life](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-life) is a rather general/generic topic not restricted to any "saving mode" and should stand on its own feet (topics here are more in the realms of identifying culprits that consume too much, or how to "take good care for your battery")
- I cannot find a [power](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power) tag (and [power-on](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-on) is a quite different topic)
- ignore the [poweramp](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poweramp) tag here

So I'd say a tag dedicated to (the different) power-saving-modes (including Stamina etc), as "generic catch" for those topics would be a good idea. Though we already have [doze-mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doze-mode): and apple is a fruit, but a fruit not necessarily an apple :) Still, at the moment I wouldn't go as far as to create a separate tag for each manufacturer's "special mode":

> Some manufacturers also offer their own battery saver modes. For example, Samsung offers an “Ultra Power Saving Mode,” HTC offers an “EXTREME Power Saving Mode,” and Sony offers a “STAMINA mode” and “Low battery mode.”

<sup>(How-To Geek: [How to Use and Configure Android’s “Battery Saver” Mode](https://www.howtogeek.com/242472/how-to-use-and-configure-androids-battery-saver-mode/))</sup>

---

**TL;DR:** If there are at least 5 questions you'd apply the [power-savings-mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-savings-mode) tag to, I'd say just do it